# override backbone's view function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, overriding

Suppose a backbone view such as

```
var Row = Backgrid.Row = Backbone.View.extend({

  foo: function() {}

}
```

I want to redefine the `foo` function from outside of this source code.
Because the code above is itself a library as well.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inheritance in JavaScript is based on prototypes. Each class constructor has `prototype` property, where you can define methods of objects it will create.

```
Backgrid.Row.prototype.foo = function () {
    // new code
}
```

It will replace existing implementation of `foo` for all `Backgrid.Row` instances, unless they have their own `foo` property.

```
var row = new Backgrid.Row();
row.foo = function () { ... }; // row now has it's personal `foo` implementation
```

I should tell that it is advised to create new class instead

```
var MyRow = Backgrid.Row.extend({ foo: function () {} });
```